# Getting thumbnails for files(first page) using SkyDrive api ios

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios5.1, onedrive

Am created one ios books reader application.. In this application am integrated google drive and skydrive.. Now i can able to signin and retrive datas from google drive and skydrive.. 
   
In google drive i can able to get thumbnail views of my files.. In google drive have an option for getting thumbnails.. Using thumbnail url. 

 In sky drive i searched a lot i cant able to get for this.. Is it possible to get thumbnails of my files(First page) in Sky drive

Really am working on two days in that.. I cant able to get any resource.. So pls help me

Answer (score 0):

I understand your sincerity. No one will help for this, because there is no source to get first page of thumbnail directly. So you should work hard and write code in your self to get this done. Good Luck...

Thanks,
Senthil.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the SkyDrive API developers. Their documentation is incomplete. Maybe there is a way to get the thumbnail of a file however it is not indicated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to get the file thumbnail from SkyDrive iOS API. In the JSON data-model you receive from the SkyDrive API, retrieve value for the key "picture". This value is a string with the thumbnail-download-url. Here's how you'll get it(assuming jsonFileModel is an NSDictionary* representing a SkyDrive file):

```
    NSString *thumbnailDownloadURL = [jsonFileModel objectForKey: @"picture"];
```